# How can I display prop of an HTML element in onClick handler of the same element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im still learning ReactJS and Ive come across this obstacle.
Im trying to create tic tac toe game. Right now I want every cell of the game's board to have a different prop called 'number' which will be the element's ID and an onclick handler that will display the ID. For now, since Im still developing the idea, only one element got the number prop. For now I only get undefined My code looks like this:

```
var React = require('react');

var Plansza3x3 = React.createClass({
  toggleClick: function() {
    alert(this.props.number);
  },

  render: function() {

  return (
    <div className="parent">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="cell" number="3" onClick={this.toggleClick}></div>
      <div className="cell"></div>
      <div className="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="cell"></div>
      <div className="cell"></div>
      <div className="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="cell"></div>
      <div className="cell"></div>
      <div className="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>//parent
)//return
}//render
})//createClass

module.exports = Plansza3x3;
```

Also, Im not sure exactly when, but sometimes the onclick triggers itself on render. Could anybody explain why?

EDIT: I've tried to convert my code into ES6 as some of you adviced me to do. Also, while doing so I've thought of another conception which is that I create 9 objects in the Plansza3x3 state. Every object got its own fieldNumber (which would be the ID I want to display). Then on render inside div.parent I want to create 3 div.rows that will contain 3 div.cell each. As you can see I tried slicing the objects that contain information for div.cells into three parts with slice into an array with 3 elements, each one containin data for three div.cells. Then I wanted to map through all of them so I get three rows with three cells each. On render I get an error saying that there is an unexpected token and it points the for loop. The code:

```
var style = require('./Plansza3x3.css');

var React = require('react');

class Plansza3x3 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            boardGameFields: [
                {fieldNumber: 1},
                {fieldNumber: 2},
                {fieldNumber: 3},
                {fieldNumber: 4},
                {fieldNumber: 5},
                {fieldNumber: 6},
                {fieldNumber: 7},
                {fieldNumber: 8},
                {fieldNumber: 9}
            ]
        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className="parent">
                {
                    for(var i = 0; i = 2; i++) {
                        <div className="row">
                            {var currentRowFieldsArray = this.state.boardGameFields.slice(3*i, (3*i)+1, (3*i)+2);
                                currentRowFieldsArray.map(currentField =>
                                    <div className="cell" key={currentField.fieldNumber} fieldNumber={currentField.fieldNumber} onClick={e => alert(e.target.fieldNumber)}></div>
                                )//map
                            }
                        </div>//row
                    }//for
                }
            </div>//parent
        )//return
    }//render
}//class

export default Plansza3x3;
```

Comment: That should print out the `number` property. Can you show us the render function of the parent element so we can see how you're passing the property? As for the function getting called on render, that usually happens if you do something like this: `onClick={this.function()}`, cos that calls it as soon as you render. If you want to call a function (particularly one with an argument) you can use this: `onClick={() => this.function(someValue)}`

Comment: In the parents render method i only have <Plansza3x3 />. Im passing the number property only how ive showed before, because i thought that was the right way to do it. 

About the automatic trigger on render - i get what you mean, but in my example i didnt write the parenthesis, so i believe this way im not calling the function right away. but still, if its inside onClick then shouldnt it by default be trigger after user clicks on something?

Comment: Ok well then you're not passing the value down as a property. You need something like `<Plansza3x3 number={5} />`

Comment: i understand what you mean, but my Plansza3x3 element has all the divs (gameboard cells) inside itself so i think i have to define the number props on the divs themselves which are inside the Plansza3x3 and what you are saying would pass only one 'number' prop to all the divs?

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean. In that case you should make a 'Row' React component that has the number as a property. That's the advantage of React, so you don't have to copy paste stuff. So have a row component that just returns a row div encasing 3 cell divs, then in your Plansza3x3 component you can just have `<Row number={5} />` for as many rows as you want

Comment: Yes, i understand, but it would give the number only to whole rows, and not every cell on its own right? What im getting at is that i want every div.cell have its own, unique number so every field on the board would have its own id, ranging from 1 up to 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `data-number` instead of `number`. Considering that the `data-number` is harcoded you can retrieve it from event like `e.target.getAttribute('data-number')`

```js
var Plansza3x3 = React.createClass({
      toggleClick: function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-number'));
      },
    
      render: function() {
    
      return (
        <div className="parent">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="cell" data-number="3" onClick={this.toggleClick}>1</div>
          <div className="cell">2</div>
          <div className="cell">3</div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="cell">4</div>
          <div className="cell">5</div>
          <div className="cell">6</div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="cell"></div>
          <div className="cell"></div>
          <div className="cell"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
    }
    })

ReactDOM.render(<Plansza3x3/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Now suppose you want it to be dynamic, from the parent you have number like

In parent:

```
number = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];

<Plansza3x3 number={number}/>
```

In Child

```
var React = require('react');

var Plansza3x3 = React.createClass({
  toggleClick: function(row, cell) {
    alert(this.props.number[row][cell]);
  },

  render: function() {

  return (
    <div className="parent">
    {this.props.number.map((num, row) => {
         return <div className="row" key={row}>
                 {num.map((cell, cell) => {
                        return <div key={cell} className="cell" number={cell} onClick={this.toggleClick.bind(this, row, cell)}></div>

                 })}
    })}

  </div>//parent
)//return
}//render
})//createClass

module.exports = Plansza3x3;
```

Comment: Ive tried your first proposition with the hardcoded value and it is still undefined. do you have any idea why it could be that way?

Comment: Updated the answer :). make use of data-number

Comment: great! that was exactly what i was looking for! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass no event to the onClick method, the method will be called by default. 
To prevent this, you can call it like this : 
`onClick={e => this.toggleClick(e)}`

Now, an advice : use ES6, it suits way more React than older JS.

Comment: I've tried it your way. My onclick on the div.cell right now looks like this:

<div className="cell" number="5" onClick={(e) => this.toggleClick(e)} style={cellColor}></div>

And the toggleClick funtion:
toggleClick: function(e) {
    alert(e.target.number);
  }

Yet still after the click I get that the prop 'number' is undefined